# Hiding previously selected option from the a select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this drop-down.

```
<select id="dDown">
     <option value="a">a</option>
     <option value="b">b</option>
     <option value="c">c</option>
</select>
```

If I first selected `b`, the next time I click the same `dDown`, the only option will display should be `a` and `c`. If I choose `a`, the next `dDown` options should be `b` and `c`.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

**Disable the selected option**

```js
$("#dDown").change(function() {
  $("option", this).prop("disabled", false)
  $("option:selected", this).prop("disabled", true)


})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="dDown">
  <option value="a">a</option>
  <option value="b">b</option>
  <option value="c">c</option>
</select>
```

**Hide the selected option**

```js
$("#dDown").change(function() {
  $("option", this).show()
  $("option:selected", this).hide()


})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="dDown">
  <option value="a">a</option>
  <option value="b">b</option>
  <option value="c">c</option>
</select>
```

You can use `.prop()` to disabled the option or use .hide() if you want to hide.

Comment: I was also thinking of disabling option. [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/f1x5p6a1/). You need to enable it again on selection of other option. Same is with the hide/show.

Comment: That works Tushar, but IE doesn't like this 'hide' approach. I need to explore further.  Thanks you and this means a lot to me.

Comment: Thanks @Guradio for looking into this.  Appreciate your help.  I am now looking for some ways to handle this hide() on IE.